# iPhone In-App Advertising

Tags: iphone

I'm strongly considering making a free version of my app that is ad-supported, but I don't exactly understand how it works.  Do you get paid every time an ad is displayed or only when the user taps it?  Can someone please explain how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Ad Network you sign up with. Some pay you for the number of impressions some for the number of clicks.

Do a search for "IPhone Ad Network", you'll find a list of companies that handle these types of placements and you can contact them about rates.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single answer to your question - it really depends on how you choose to approach including ads, which isn't really a question for StackOverflow but rather for ad agencies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get a single answer to this, each agency does things differently.

There is a free ad rotating component [AdWhirl](http://www.adwhirl.com/) that tries to abstract things for you, this would likely be a good place to start.